# Maximum parallel requests on SPDY connection

Tags: browser, spdy

Do browsers impose a limit on max parallel requests on a SPDY connection? If yes, could you please share link(s) explaining this setting and the max value used by different browsers?

Comment: Just curious, how many connections are you trying to make per page load?

Comment: My page needs roughly 40 micro javascript libraries. In non-spdy world, I combine them together into a single giant JS file. But in spdy world, I would like to keep them separate and hence achieve higher cache hits on the browser. Will browser, with spdy support, fetch all 40 of them in parallel OR it will group them into batches due to max parallel requests limit?

Comment: I'm unsure of a browser's limit, but SPDY is fast, and you should test both versions of your site.  www.httpvshttps.com uses SPDY